# Recover Windows 8.1 MBR without a working Windows system available

Tags: windows-8, bootloader, mbr, bcd

I just screwed over my MBR and Windows won't boot. I don't have a working Windows system available to create a recovery USB disk. My laptop doesn't have a CDROM drive.

How do I create a recovery disk without a working Windows system?

**EDIT**

I got a recovery pendrive for Windows 8. Automatic repair and similars will fail. Going to the command line and trying to use **bootrec /rebuildbcd** will fail too (device not found or something like that).

I'm losing hope.

Comment: What do you have working (ie. the device/OS you used to post this question)?

Comment: Windows 7 or Debian Linux.

Comment: From the recovery pendrive try `bootrec /fixmbr`.

Comment: This command ia case sensetive. Use:
BootRec.exe /RebuildBcd

Answer (score 2):

I *just* went through this. MBR's on 8.1 seem to be as fragile as porcelain, mine breaks on nearly every reboot. You need access to a computer of *some sort.* You can access the recovery from a full windows 8.1 (Windows 8 WILL NOT WORK) iso / install drive. [This site](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-tip-download-windows-81-iso-windows-8-product-key) has instructions on downloading the ISO from microsoft. Although I'm sure there are torrents that are easier to track down. Make a bootable USB drive using this ISO, (on windows 7, you can use [this tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) from MS) and you will have access to the recovery drive.